# reading pandas frame from sqlite3 using variable in where clause

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I have a fairly large sqlite3 database and sometimes I get a memory error when trying to read it into a Pandas dataframe.  I can use the WHERE function to limit the size of the frame so that it will work.

```
con = sqlite3.connect("myDB.db")
frame = pd_sql.read_frame('SELECT * FROM Basketball WHERE League == "NBA"', pinnyCon)
```

How would I name a variable so that something like this would work?

```
def GetLeagueFrame(leagueName):
    con = sqlite3.connect("myDB.db")
    frame = pd_sql.read_frame('SELECT * FROM Basketball WHERE League == leagueName', pinnyCon)
    con.close()
    return frame
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameter substitution with `?` for that:

```
pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM Basketball WHERE League = ?', con, params=(leagueName, ))
```

See the [`read_sql_query` docstring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html) for more explanation on the `params` keyword.